# How to create a custom parallelogram in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can anybody help to make such kind of shape in React Native ?

I tried in this way but desire output is different

```
parallelogram: {
        width: 200,
        height: 65,
        transform: [{ skewY: '-30deg' }],
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: "red"
    },
```

[our actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ufd3.png)

but i want this type of shape which is mention in below image.
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DMSx.png)